# Как передать данные из компонента в корневой документ Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Только начал знакомство с Vue Cli.
Пишу свое первое приложение.

Есть такая структура:

```
components/
  /header.vue
    /user/
      /user_panel.vue
      /user.vue
  /popups.vue
    /loginForm.vue
```

Хочу из user.vue отслеживать событие клика, при котором будет открываться форма авторизации. А в popups.vue подключены все папупы.
Нужно обрабатывать события и открывать пупапы, но я не знаю как передать сразу в корень минуя родителя в данном случае header.vue. Или даже лучше как написать глобальный метод, чтобы обрабатывать открытие   всех пупапов?

Comment: А при чём тут `vue-cli`? Вы можете использовать `vuex`.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал доку. Да нужен vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Vuex,

или

Возможно попробовать  Provide-Inject
(во Vue2 подключить composition Api)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api